# iOS: Is it possible to get iTunes app link from iOS application programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store-connect, itunes

Is there any way of getting own iTunes app link programmatically from application itself. I am aware of getting app identifier, but unsure of app link. If yes then how can I ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=<appid>

<appid> is id of app. Result of this is JSON with info about the app.
```

Comment: Can we get this <appid> app id programatically? Or do we need to hardcore this?

Comment: You can take it from iTunes Connect, and hardcode it into app. During its life on Appstore, that number is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=<appid>
```

This will return JSON response containing app details such as supported device, app description, user rating etc.

Filter JSON and fetch ***trackViewUrl*** key in ***results*** JSON